# VB.NET Sending a SQL query to an .accdb file

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

At the code: DatabaseAdapter.Fill(DatabaseDataSet, "Runway") I am getting the following error, please help as I have tried looking at other sources for answers but they didn't solve my problem.
Thanks :)
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

```
Sub GetDatabaseInfo(ByVal ICAOcodeEntered As String)
       Dim DatabaseConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim DatabaseAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Const DataProvider As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        Const DataSource As String = "Data Source=Airport Database.accdb"
        DatabaseConnection.ConnectionString = DataProvider & DataSource

        DatabaseConnection.Open()

        Dim DatabaseDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet

        DatabaseAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(
            "SELECT Runway.* FROM Runway, [Airport Information] WHERE [Airport Information].[Airport ID] = Runway.[Airport ID] AND [Airport Information].[ICAO Code]=" _
        & ICAOcodeEntered & ";", DatabaseConnection)

        DatabaseAdapter.Fill(DatabaseDataSet, "Runway")

        MsgBox(DatabaseDataSet.Tables("Runway").Rows(0).Item(1))

        DatabaseConnection.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: This message is usually emitted by the Access engine when one or more of your field or table names are not recognized. Check the names used, _Airport Information, ICAO Code, Airport ID, Runway_ they should all exist as spelled in your database.

Comment: Runway.[Airport ID] where you get from, i think that is a problem

Answer (score 0):

Your string isn't enclosed in single quotation marks, but you should always use parameters:

```vb
Using adp As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Runway...
  ...AND [Airport Information].[ICAO Code] = ?", DatabaseConnection)

  adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ICAOcodeEntered)
  adp.Fill(DatabaseDataSet, "Runway")
End Using
```